# Insert new line after various amount of numeric characters

Tags: sed

I need to insert a new line, or delimiter, in a text file after a "numeric" string consisting of 10 numbers, then a "-", then either 1 to 4 numbers...

Example:

```
blahblahrandomtext,1234567890-1234blahblah
```

Should be:

```
blahblahrandomtext,1234567890-1234, blahblah
```

Or:

```
blahblahrandomtext,1234567890-1234

blahblah
```

Note that the first set of numbers will always be 10 characters, the numbers after the - will either 1,2,3 or 4 characters, e.g.

```
1234567890-1
1234567890-12
1234567890-123
1234567890-1234
```

I've used sed a lot for similar tasks, but can't find a way to work with the last set of numbers which vary from 1 to 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to do it with a fixed number of digits, you should know how to do it with a maximum and minimum of repeated chars: Inside the `\{\}` place the minimum and maximum separated by a comma like this:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{10\}-[0-9]\{1,4\}/&,\n/'
```

for GNU `sed`; for other versions, use a backslash followed by a literal newline instead of `\n`

Comment: Worked perfectly, it was the, maximum and the minimum I was having trouble with... Marked as best answer..

Answer (score 3):

**sed** solution (to insert delimiter `,`):

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{10}-[0-9]{1,4}/\1&, /' file
```

- `-E` - apply extended regular expressions
- `(^|[^0-9])` matches either the beginning of a line or a non-digit. This ensures that no numbers with more than 10 digits match
- `&` - points to the whole matched string

The output:

```
blahblahrandomtext,1234567890-1234, blahblah
```

Comment: Works for this example, but will fail for `foo1234567890-42bar`. Perhaps better use `(^|[^0-9])` instead of `\<`

Comment: @Philippos, I thought that that "numeric" string should be somehow isolated, but, It seems not. Updated

Comment: No, don't do that. That's the main improvement you made over my answer. As in most questions, we don't really know the whole spectrum of possible input data. My answer (and your edited version) will also accept eleven digits before the dash. Your `\<` takes care of that, but has other limitations. `[^0-9]` before the match would limit to 10 digits, but fail on the beginning of the line. So `(^|[^0-9])` should cover everything: Only match exactly 10 digits before the dash, no matter whether they appear on the beginning of the line, after letters or other characters.

Comment: @Philippos, updated, just for the case if someone(except the OP) would need a proper approach